# Using agvtool with multiple .xcodeproject files in one directory

Tags: ios, build, versioning, projects, agvtool

I have tried using agvtool for ios build versionining. It works great when there is a single .xcodeproj file in the directory. In my case, our project structure is such that it has 4 .xcodeproj files in a single directory. When firing agvtool command in this directory it throws error message, 'agvtool does not work with multiple projects in the same directory'. Anyone has any idea how can I make agvtool work with this folder structure?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

For people finding this post and using Fastlane, I just wanted to tell about the plugin `https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning` which have a `increment_version_number_in_plist` command which does not use agvtool (and support multiple .xcodeproj files in a single folder.

You just need to install the plugin above and replace your `increment_version_number` action with `increment_version_number_in_plist` .. they have a very similar contract.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there were actually 2 xcode project files. i.e. projectName.xcodeproj and projectNameModule.xcodeproj. That happened as I removed some commits where we updated the project name from projectName to projectNameModule. For some reason even after reverting those name changes, the project *Module.xcodeproj and *Module.xcworkspace files were still existing.
I just deleted those unused files and it fixed the issue for me.